# Alternative for Chrome's Coverage in Firefox

Tags: javascript, frontend, firefox-addon, firefox-developer-tools

I've just discovered an interesting function in Chrome, to show which parts of the code are not being used in the running page/application.

More details here: [Chrome devtools Coverage](https://developers.google.com/web/tools/chrome-devtools/coverage)

I wasn't able to find and alternative for Firefox, does anybody know if it exists natively in the browser, or if there are any extensions capable of the same functionality?

Thanks

Comment: Note that Chrome's code coverage tool currently only checks the coverage on a single page. I.e. if you have different pages on your website using different parts of your CSS or JavaScript, the coverage is actually higher than shown by that tool. Also, your code may have parts working only in a specific browser, e.g. prefixed CSS properties, which are not recognized by that tool. These two restrictions limit its usefulness.

Comment: This could make possible to have coverage using Firefox in Playwright, a feature I miss a lot.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The simple but unfortunate answer is no, Firefox (version 82) doesn't include a code coverage tool and there isn't any Firefox extension allowing to do that so far.

There is only an [enhancement request asking for adding a code coverage feature](https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=1430488) like the one in Chrome.

Comment: Thanks Sebastian, I suspected that... Also it seems that WebStorm is supporting the function (https://www.jetbrains.com/help/webstorm/capturing-unused-javascript-code.html) but I suppose that it's based on Chrome. Also I've found a webpack plugin which seems to find unused files: https://github.com/MQuy/webpack-deadcode-plugin. Unfortunately it doesn't find unused code but only files. It would be very nice to have that function, I discovered that half of my CSS code was "dead"

Comment: You're right, WebStorm's code coverage feature obviously uses Chrome's tooling according to the page you linked to. As I wrote in a comment to your question, doing proper code coverage is extremely hard to do and that Chrome's tool (and I assume the others too) only do basic checks and therefore incorrectly mark code as unused. I've [outlined some more advanced checks](https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=1430488#c4) in a comment to the Firefox enhancement request I linked to in my answer.

Comment: Yeah I've read your comment! Well now I installed chrome since more than 2yrs that I was using Firefox. The feature is useful, but you know, is not something that you use everyday...but it's definitively something handy, so I hope that it will be implemented in the future, I like firefox :-)